# Windows phone 8 - file system

Tags: windows-phone-8, filesystems

At the beginning I would like to notice that I have no experience at creating Windows Phone applications.

Is there a way to access Windows Phone 8 "user space" file system (the directory you see when you connect phone to pc) in order to view folders structure or read/write files, eg. with .txt extention?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) integrated file browser.